# Accessing a specific cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
A    B    C    D
1    2    3   200
4    2    5   300
5    5    3   100
```

Assuming that the combination between the `A` and `B` values is unique, how can I (efficiently as possible) get the `C` value of a certain column based on the `A` and `B` values?
For example, how can I get the `C` value of the column which satisfies `A = 4 & B = 2`?

I tried to read about `loc` and `iloc`, but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the values of A and B, and then use `loc` to grab the value of A:

```
A_val = 4
B_val = 2

df.loc[(df['A'] == A_val) & (df['B'] == B_val)]['C'][1] # -- > the 1 at the end will just grab the number
```

which prints:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want this.

```
df.loc[(df['A']==4) & (df['B']==2)].loc[:,'C']
```

Prints

```
1    5
Name: C, dtype: int64
```